# How do I set up a lambda function in AWS to install certain packages and dependencies

Tags: aws-lambda

I know there are deployment packages but what are these? Can they contain bash scripts that do apt-get install?

Is there any way to build a lambda function that uses a particular AMI

Comment: Is there any way to create a blueprint or pattern that includes tools such as R? It doesn't seem possible to create a blueprint like you can create an AMi

Comment: Lambda machines use latest versions of Amazon Linux that's very similar to CentOS.

Comment: But it seems like there is no choice of AMI

Comment: Correct, it's up to your deployment to make sure you have all the dependencies installed.

Comment: Is there an easy way to find the ami that it does use so I can investigate whether I can do it via maybe pip? I guess I could use Python shell commands to provide some dependencies. It does seem like an anti-pattern. But just need some R bindings like rpy2

Comment: You can try this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html But I'm not sure that it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not not supported via the provided docker Lambda images for example `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8`.

You can run shell commands from inside your code(so technically you could run shell scripts) but you are charged for the time it takes your Lambda to execute - so installing a bunch of dependencies every time the Lambda starts up would be considered an anti-pattern.

You need to bundle all the packages and dependencies with your Lambda. This is done by uploading a zip file that contains the lambda function and all the dependencies.

You can see the official docs for the various supported languages here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-java-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: For including OS-level dependencies, is there any way to include those dependencies in the lambda layers or ZIP?  Eg. sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev, etc..

Comment: The cited AWS creation docs only describe how I can install extra Python packages. But not Linux packages.

Answer (score 1):

I think your are looking for something like [lambda-uploader](https://github.com/rackerlabs/lambda-uploader). You can list out the python packages required by your lambda. If you come across a package that requires a couple of library files to run, you can include them as well. Like for example, the **mysql-python** package requires *libmysqlclient.so* and *_mysql.so* files to run properly.

It generates the .zip file for you and deletes it once it has been uploaded. This way, you can avoid manual packaging steps and make deployment a breeze.